# File Upload to a folder in server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

i just want to save an uploaded file to a folder in server. My System design has UI and server part.The UI Is fully HTML and the server side is ASP.net. The data transfer is through json code.

Suppose i have an HTML file control in UI then how can i upload this to server.

Can anyone advise me with an example

code sample

```
 $("#btn_AddDoc").click( function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var InsDocDet = {};
          InsDocDet.docname=$("#DocName").val();

          InsDocDet.ownerUser=1;
          InsDocDet.catid=$("#drp_cat").val();
          InsDocDet.createDatetime=new Date();
          InsDocDet.description_d=$("#Desc").val();
          InsDocDet.comments_=$("#cmnts").val();
          InsDocDet.deptid_=1;
          InsDocDet.con_type=1;
          InsDocDet.size_=1;
          InsDocDet.Doc_status="up";
          var fullPath =$("#doc_upload").val(); //document.getElementById('doc_upload').value;
          if (fullPath) {
          var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
          var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
          if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
          filename = filename.substring(1);
          InsDocDet.file_name=filename;
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
            // <!-- url: "http://localhost/EMRDMSService/Service.asmx/User_Login",-->
             url: "http://localhost/EMRDMSService/Service.asmx/srv_Insert_Document",
              data: "{ins_Doc:" + JSON.stringify(InsDocDet) + "}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (r) {                     
                              console.log(r.d.STAT);
              }
          });
      });
```

in web service

```
public string srv_Insert_Document(insert_doc_details ins_Doc)
{
    InsDoc_Ret doc_ret = new InsDoc_Ret();
    try
    {

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(ins_Doc.file_name);
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/");
        File_Doc.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Files/" + dept_name + "/", filename)));
        string ctype = File_Doc.PostedFile.ContentType;
        int len = File_Doc.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        double size = len / 1024;
        string sizkb = Convert.ToString(size) + " KB";
        string fname = dept_name + "/" + filename;






        int doc_id = newdb_class.Insert_Data_Scaler("INSERT INTO dms_document_details (DOC_NAME,FILE_NAME,OWNER_USER,CAT_ID,CREATE_DATE,DESCRIPTION,COMMENTS,DEPT_ID,contype,Size,DocStatus) VALUES ('" + ins_Doc.docname + "','" + ins_Doc.file_name + "','" + ins_Doc.ownerUser + "','" + ins_Doc.catid + "',NOW(),'" + ins_Doc.description_d + "','" + ins_Doc.comments_ + "','" + ins_Doc.deptid_ + "','" + ins_Doc.con_type + "','" + ins_Doc.size_ + "','" + ins_Doc.Doc_status + "')");
        doc_ret.SID = "1";
        doc_ret.STAT="SUCCESS";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        doc_ret.SID = "1";
        doc_ret.STAT = "FAIL";
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js.Serialize(doc_ret);
    return strJSON;

}
```

here in this code the "File_Doc" in service refers to the file upload control in asp.net. so how can ireplace it with html file control.

---

i got some code

```
 public string srv_Insert_Document(insert_doc_details ins_Doc)
{
    InsDoc_Ret doc_ret = new InsDoc_Ret();
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = newdb_class.Read_Data("SELECT Dept_Name FROM dms_dept_details WHERE Dept_id='" + ins_Doc.deptid_ + "'");
        string dept_name = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim();
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(ins_Doc.file_name);
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/");
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Files/" + dept_name + "/", filename)));
        }

        string ctype = file.ContentType;
        int len = file.ContentLength;
        double size = len / 1024;
        string sizkb = Convert.ToString(size) + " KB";


        string fname_ins = dept_name + "/" + filename;






        int doc_id = newdb_class.Insert_Data_Scaler("INSERT INTO dms_document_details (DOC_NAME,FILE_NAME,OWNER_USER,CAT_ID,CREATE_DATE,DESCRIPTION,COMMENTS,DEPT_ID,contype,Size,DocStatus) VALUES ('" + ins_Doc.docname + "','" + ins_Doc.file_name + "','" + ins_Doc.ownerUser + "','" + ins_Doc.catid + "',NOW(),'" + ins_Doc.description_d + "','" + ins_Doc.comments_ + "','" + ins_Doc.deptid_ + "','" + ins_Doc.con_type + "','" + ins_Doc.size_ + "','" + ins_Doc.Doc_status + "')");
        doc_ret.SID = "1";
        doc_ret.STAT="SUCCESS";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        doc_ret.SID = "1";
        doc_ret.STAT = "FAIL";
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js.Serialize(doc_ret);
    return strJSON;

}
```

but I got an error in `HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];`

ie request does not exist in the current context

Comment: It will be more easy to get an answer if you'll post few of code...

Comment: http://bit.ly/17xgjIl

Comment: @code Rider--i stuck with this issue. ie i dont know what exactly to do this..please provide code samples if uhave...

Comment: you should use ajax's asyncfileUploader. i think there isn't any way to pass an image from client side to server side.

Comment: can anyone provide a code sample

Answer (score 1):

No. Uploading a file need a full postback.

You can simulate an ajax call posting to a hidden iFrame (so your page don't change). Then checking the content of the iFrame using jquery/javascript you can see if the upload was successful and do a refresh of certain part of your screen.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC3 or MVC4 here is an example: http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2011/11/16/AJAX-File-Uploads-with-jQuery-and-MVC-3.aspx

If you want a more generic way of doing it in JS: http://tips.itliveweb.com/ajax/upload-image-using-iframe-javascript-ajax.html

Comment: when i use file upload ie html control ,then is it be saved to any temporary path?

Comment: yup. i posted some links. can't they help you?

Comment: check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery